# Ruby create array form git log?

Tags: ruby, arrays, git, split

I'm coding in Ruby to extract a list of git authors using:

```
git log --since=#{from} --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>"
```

However, this returns a string like so:

```
<author>first, last</author>
<author>first, last</author> 
...and so forth down the string...
```

How can I split that string into an array in Ruby?

Comment: Do you want the firstname and the lastname in one Array?

Comment: I want it split so that each element contains <author>first last</author>

Comment: You could try a substring to divide the list using 
`yourtext[minlength..maxlength]`
and then add it into an Array with a for loop.
!OBS! The minlength and maxlength are the numbers of letters,

Comment: The first and last names change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use split to split on newlines:

```
authors_string = `git log --since=#{from} --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>"`
authors_array  = authors_string.split($/)
```

I'm using `$/` here which holds the line ending for your OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
# 's' contains authors, the string returned by 'git log'
s.split "\n"
=> ["<author>first last</author>", "<author>first last</author>"]
```